# Housing dataset from Hands On Machine Learning with Sci-Kit Learn & Tensorflow does not display when I try to recreate it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to recreate the housing dataset/code from the book by using the code below. For some reason I get the error that is displayed all the way in the end

```
In [32]:

import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib
In [37]:

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = "/home/isaac/Fundamentals of Data Science Certificate/3253 - Machine Learning/Code from book"
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + HOUSING_PATH + "/housing.tgz"
In [41]:

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
In [42]:

import pandas as pd
def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
In [43]:

housing = load_housing_data()
housing.head
```

---

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'/home/isaac/Fundamentals of Data Science Certificate/3253 - Machine Learning/Code from book/housing.csv' does not exist
```

​

How would I solve this?

Comment: "does not exist" - Seems self explanatory. Does folder exist and do you have permission to access it?

Comment: Yes, the folder does exist. How would I check whether I have a permission to access it or not? Hold on, gonna copy paste the code into my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `fetch_housing_data` anywhere to create file `'housing.tgz'`

(You are also assuming that the file `'housing.tgz'` contains a zipped version of the file `"housing.csv"`)

Comment: So, I am following along the code from https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb and it seems like I missed fetch_housing_data() line. After running it, it tells me that HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Seems like we found a problem

Answer (score 2):

import pandas as pd
fetch_housing_data()

After importing the pandas. Just call the function fetch_housing_data(). This should fix the problem.

The book has similar mistakes where author has forgot to add a line or two.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your 5th and 6th lines follow the format as suggested in the book

```
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"
```

Also, you'd want to call `fetch_housing_data()` between your function and the numpy import.

Using the format above, I was just able to fetch the data in a Jupyter notebook myself.

Answer (score 0):

adding the line fetch_housing_data() should do the needful after defining fetch_housing_data and before importing pd.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem as you. Follow the below code, it will solve your problems.

See the code from this GitHub repo of the book 
Link: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb

```
In [2]:
import os
import tarfile
import urllib.request

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()

In [3]:
fetch_housing_data()

In [4]:
import pandas as pd

def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

In [5]:
housing = load_housing_data()
housing.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case I use pycharm IDE to keep code organized, I kept this one as a separate file to re-use this code in future.

> 1. getCsv.py

```
import os
import tarfile
import urllib.request

import pandas as pd


def load_housing_data(housing_path, housing_url):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

2. In main.py, Call this function from main.py by passing required parameters.

> ```
> import os
>
> from GetCSVUsingPanda import load_housing_data
>
> DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
> HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
> HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"
>
> housing = load_housing_data(HOUSING_PATH, HOUSING_URL)
> housing_head = housing.head()
> print(housing_head)
> ```

All the best!